# lisp conditional call function

Tags: macros, lisp, max

How to write a macro "MAXF" : find max value in a parameter list , then call a specific function? e.g.

```
(defun func (x y z) (format t "~A ~A ~A~%" x y z))


(let ((a 1) (b 1))
  (maxf ((+ a b 1) (func a b 1))   ((+ a b 2) (func a b 2))... ((+ a b 100) 
(func a b 100)) )
```

The result should be: "1 1 100"

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do (and what problem you're having) a bit more.

Comment: I backtrace a path in a matrix, try to identify a maximum value (in diagonal, up, left directions) , then make a step. Here by maxf,  (+ a b 100) is found the max, then a b 100 should be printed: "1 1 100"

Comment: A macro cannot help you since it does not know anything about `a`,  and `b` at compile time. Your macro will get `(+ a b 1)` as list structure, not the calculated values. Remove the excess parentheses and you can make a function `(max (+ a b 1) (dunc a b 1) ...)` with use of `&rest` argument.